# SQL Server 2012 buckets based on running total

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum, cumulative-sum

For SQL Server 2012, I am trying to assign given rows to sequential buckets based on the maximum size of the bucket (100 in the sample below) and running total of a column. Most of the solutions I found partition by known column changing value e.g. partition by department id etc. However, in this situation all I have is sequential id and size. The closest solution I have found is discussed in this thread  for SQL Server 2008 and I tried it but the performance very slow for large row set much worse than cursor based solution. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45179/how-can-i-write-windowing-query-which-sums-a-column-to-create-discrete-buckets

This table can contain up to 10 Million rows. With SQL Server 2012 supporting SUM OVER and LAG and LEAD functions, wondering if someone can suggest a solution based on 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
id    INT PRIMARY KEY
, size  INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO raw_data
(id, size)
VALUES 
  ( 1,    96) -- new bucket here, maximum bucket size is 100
, ( 2,    10) -- and here
, ( 3,    98) -- and here
, ( 4,    20)
, ( 5,    50)
, ( 6,    15)
, ( 7,    97)
, ( 8,    96) -- and here
;

--Expected output
--bucket_size is for illustration only, actual needed output is bucket only

id  size    bucket_size bucket
-----------------------------
1   100     100         1
2    10     10          2
3    98     98          3
4    20     85          4
5    50     85          4
6    15     85          4
7    97     98          5
8    1      98          5
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this quite easily in SQL Server 2012 using a window function and framing.  The syntax looks quite complex, but the concept is simple - sum all the previous rows up to and including the current one.  The cumulative_bucket_size column in this example is for demonstration purposes, as it is part of the equation used to derive the bucket number:

```
DECLARE @Bucket_Size AS INT;
SET @Bucket_Size = 100

SELECT
    id,
    size,
    SUM(size) OVER  (
                        PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY id ASC
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                    ) AS cumulative_bucket_size,
    1 + SUM(size) OVER  (
                        PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY id ASC
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                    ) / @Bucket_Size AS bucket
FROM
    raw_data
```

The PARTITION BY clause is optional, but would be useful if you had different "bucket sets" for column groupings.  I have added it here for completeness.

Results:

```
id  size    cumulative_bucket_size  bucket
------------------------------------------
1   96      96                      1
2   10      106                     2
3   98      204                     3
4   20      224                     3
5   50      274                     3
6   15      289                     3
7   97      386                     4
8   96      482                     5
```

You can read more about windows framing in the following article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-2-the-frame/

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the running total method to assign bucket numbers, you need to generate that `bucket_size` column, because the numbers would be produced based on that column.

Based on your expected output, the bucket ranges are

```
1..10
11..85
86..100
```

You could use a simple CASE expression like this to generate a `bucket_size` column like in your example:

```
CASE
    WHEN size <= 10 THEN 10
    WHEN size <= 85 THEN 85
    ELSE 100
END
```

Then you would use LAG() to determine if a row starts a new sequence of sizes belonging to the same bucket:

```
CASE bucket_size
    WHEN LAG(bucket_size) OVER (ORDER BY id) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
```

These two calculations could be done in the same (sub)query with the help of CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.size,
    x.bucket_size,  -- for illustration only
    is_new_seq = CASE x.bucket_size
                     WHEN LAG(x.bucket_size) OVER (ORDER BY d.id) THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                 END
FROM dbo.raw_data AS d
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN size <= 10 THEN 10
            WHEN size <= 85 THEN 85
            ELSE 100
        END
) AS x (bucket_size)
```

The above query [would produce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7ec9/1) this output:

```
id  size  bucket_size  is_new_seq
--  ----  -----------  ----------
1   96    100          1
2   10    10           1
3   98    100          1
4   20    85           1
5   50    85           0
6   15    85           0
7   97    100          1
8   96    100          0
```

Now use that result as a derived table and apply SUM() OVER to `is_new_seq` to produce the bucket numbers, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7ec9/2):

```
SELECT
    id,
    size,
    bucket = SUM(is_new_seq) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        d.id,
        d.size,
        is_new_seq = CASE x.bucket_size
                         WHEN LAG(x.bucket_size) OVER (ORDER BY d.id) THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                     END
    FROM dbo.raw_data AS d
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN size <= 10 THEN 10
                WHEN size <= 85 THEN 85
                ELSE 100
            END
    ) AS x (bucket_size)
) AS s
;
```